# img representing custom forms in TinyMCE?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm using TinyMCE in a CMS I am developing. Part of my CMS allows the user to create forms. This uses PHP and a MySQL table in order to store all of the form fields and the order they should appear in.

I want to allow the user to insert the form into their page via TinyMCE, and just have an image or div represent the form that the user can align and place wherever they want within the content.

So far I've come up with a custom listbox with the following code:

```
ed.addButton('myforms', {
    type: 'listbox',
    text: 'Forms',
    icon: false,
    onselect: function(e) {
        ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, this.value());
    },
    values: [
        {text: 'Form 1', value: '<img id="myform-1" class="mce-object myform" width="250" height="300" alt="" />'}
    ]
});
```

I was thinking of using the simple HTML DOM parser in order to find the images with the class of `myform` and simply replace them with the actual form when the page is rendered.

This works OK, however there are a few problems:

1. The image representing the form is resizable.
2. When clicked, it activates the TinyMCE image button, allowing the image to be changed and resized.
3. It displays as an image in the source code.

I'd prefer having a DIV or a shortcode which is an mce-object that has the name of the form within it, that is movable but not editable, however I have not been able to figure this out.

Is there a solution to this problem, or am I stuck with this little hack I've come up with?

Comment: I used TinyMCE with an old CMS but found it to be inferior to ckeditor. CKEditor also has a forms plugin (http://ckeditor.com/addon/forms)

Comment: after looking into it, i am going to switch to ckeditor. thank you.

Comment: no worries. Let me know if you need a hand...